# Creating point layer from linear layer with only ends of lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have ArcGIS 10 with ArcView licence and I need to make point layer from a linear layer, with only start and end points for each line. In ArcInfo I could use Feature Vertices To Points with "both_ends" as option but I don`t have such licence.

I found "[Polyline Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=C08D8D42-1422-2418-3448-59824ECD6BF5)" script for creation point layer from linear layer with only ArcView licence, but it returns all vertices not only ends.

How can I delete all vertices from lines but ends or maybe other variant how can I make point layer from line layer with only ends of lines?

Answer (score 1):

The free ET Geowizards has a "polyline to Point" tool. There is an option, "Calculate Point position along polyline". Enabling this will add a field named ET_ORDER, 0 is the first point and 1 is the last point of each line. You can select the end-points with this, "ET_ORDER" = 0 OR "ET_ORDER" = 1, save the points to another file.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use it in ModelBuilder?

Comment: No, I cannot get it to work in modelBuilder.